# IE 11 Toggle hide and show jquery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

Apologies if this has been asked before. I have have this hide and show tab here

https://codepen.io/tpuro/pen/gOmJwyo

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.nav-tabs > li > a').click(function(event) {
            //event.preventDefault(); stop browser to take action for clicked anchor
            //get displaying tab content jQuery selector
            var active_tab_selector = $('.nav-tabs > li.active > a').attr('href');
            //find actived navigation and remove 'active' css
            var actived_nav = $('.nav-tabs > li.active');
            actived_nav.removeClass('active');
            //add 'active' css into clicked navigation
            $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
            //hide displaying tab content
            $(active_tab_selector).removeClass('active');
            $(active_tab_selector).addClass('hide');
            //show target tab content
            var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');
            $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
            $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');
          });
        });
```

Where the user click the tab they are automatically scrolled to the bottom to view the content rather than scrolling down for it. This is what the client wanted rather than the normal tab toggle we see in bootstrap.

I am not a jquery expert and disable the code event.preventDefault();
enabled the anchor tag to work and scroll below.

The code works on all modern browser but on IE 11 its completely not even toggling between the tabs  or anything. If anyone can suggest a fix for IE would be awesome.

Regards
T

Comment: Why are you using nav tabs for this? Why not just use normal anchor links? Are you getting any errors in your dev console?

Comment: I test your codepen code in IE 11, it works well. When the user clicks the tab, they are automatically scrolled to the bottom to view the content. You can check the result in IE 11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvKix.gif. Please clear browser cache and test again. Please check if you have enabled [compatibility view setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqc41.png) in the site and check if there's any error in console in IE 11.

Comment: Yu Zhou thank you its working now. It seems there was a Javascript code that was above the jquery code causing this conflict in IE11 only. By removing that helped solve the issue.

Comment: That's great that you have solved the issue! You can also put your solution into an answer and mark it as an accept answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.